# "Updates Frequently" option in Interface Builder

Tags: interface-builder

What exactly does the "Updates Frequently" option in Interface Builder do? Does it optimize the NIB for *frequent updates* somehow?

[Updates Frequently http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/5031/screenshot20100101at952.png](http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/5031/screenshot20100101at952.png)

Comment: Does anybody else find it goofy that `Accessibility` itself is unchecked (implying that it is totally unaccessible), yet users can still _access_ it via `User Interaction Enabled`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that you're looking at the Accessibility options.

See the *UIAccessibility Protocol Reference*:

> UIAccessibilityTraitUpdatesFrequently
>   The accessibility element frequently
>   updates its label or value.
>
> You can use this trait to characterize
>   an accessibility element that updates
>   its label or value too often to send
>   update notifications. Including this
>   trait allows an assistive application
>   to avoid handling continual
>   notifications and, instead, poll for
>   changes when it needs updated
>   information. For example, you might
>   use this trait to characterize the
>   readout of a stopwatch.
>
> Available in iPhone OS 3.0 and later.
>
> Declared in
>   UIAccessibilityConstants.h.

I've never needed to mess with this personally, but I think the idea is that if you had a button that had its label flash between "all" "your" base" etc every second, this would keep the voiceover thing from constantly babbling out the new word every second.